# A "how is it finding libpython?!" puzzle

Tags: python, c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to get a semi-abandoned python scientific computing package written for python 2 to compile against python 3.  My problem has to do with the linker not being able to find libpython. It's obvious why it can't find libpython from the g++ command line; what I don't get is why it works in the python 2.7 case and not in the python 3.6 case.

This works:

```
g++ -pthread -shared -fopenmp src/matrix/Matrix.o src/matrix/Statistics.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages -lpython2.7 -o condensedMatrix.so
```

This doesn't work:

```
g++ -pthread -shared -fopenmp src/matrix/Matrix.o src/matrix/Statistics.o -L/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -lpython3.6 -o condensedMatrix.so
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lpython3.6
```

*Neither* should work because the respective paths to libpython:

```
-L/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-L/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

are both incorrect:  This is an Ubuntu 18.04 system, so the libraries in question can be found here:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so
```

In the python 2.7 case, which compiles, I don't have an LD_LIBRARY_PATH set; however setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the correct location for libpython3.6.so doesn't help.

The build system used here is **build.py**.  I'm trying to figure out where it's getting the `-L/usr/lib/python*/dist-packages` directive in the g++ compile line, but meanwhile the real mystery is why the python 2.7 case compiles.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Do you have a symlink to `libpython2.7` somewhere else? If so, passing the incorrect path `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` doesn't hid the library, it just provides one more directory where `gcc` won't find it.

Comment: Just what I was thinking. What does `find /usr -name 'libpython*.so*' -ls` print?

Comment: Also, FYI, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only affects the behavior of the *dynamic* linker, not the regular linker.

Comment: When you've successfully linked the program, pass it as an argument to `ldd`.  What does that report?

Comment: @chepner No, no symlinks.  I checked for this.

Comment: @zwol That was the right tip!  libpython2.7.so had a link into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (which must be a default library location for ldd) and libpython3.6.1 didn't.  As soon as I created the link, it compiled.  Thanks!

Comment: @kaz Given that I got it working before getting to your comment, I didn't do this, but this is an excellent suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, mystery resolved, thanks to a tip in the comments.  It turns out that there was a link to **libpython2.7.1** in **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**, but *not* one for **libpython3.6.so**.  The libpython3.6-dev package did create some links there, but not ones resolving to `-lpython3.6`:

```
root@tarantula:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -l libpython3.6*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      57 Apr 17 20:56 libpython3.6m.a -> ../python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Apr 17 20:56 libpython3.6m.so -> libpython3.6m.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Apr 17 20:56 libpython3.6m.so.1 -> libpython3.6m.so.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4683728 Apr 17 20:56 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

So I created a link:

```
 # cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 # ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so .
```

and now everything compiles.  The `-L/usr/lib/python=*/dist-packages` was a misdirection that was throwing me. Since libpython isn't located there, it's looking for it in one of the default library locations instead.  My bad on that one.

Comment: The lack of a symlink to the common library name `libpython3.6.so` seems like an Ubuntu packaging error that I will report upstream.